# A question about close line segment in TVS.

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

Suppose $E$ a topological vector space,which need not be Hausdoff. $x,y\in E$ are different.

How to prove the close line segment $\{\alpha x+(1-\alpha)y:\alpha\in[0,1]\}$ is closed. And should it be compact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be compact, as the function that sends $\alpha \in [0,1]$ to $\alpha x + (1-\alpha)y$ is continuous (as all vector operations are, details omitted). And the continuous image of a compact space ($[0,1]$) is compact.

Compact need not imply closed for non-Hausdorff spaces. To give a rather extreme counterexample, suppose that $E$ has the indiscrete (a.k.a. trivial) topology: only $E$ and $\emptyset$ are open. It's quite clear (check this!) that this makes $E$ into a topological vector space, and a very non-Hausdorff one at that. The closed line segment is then not closed, as no non-empty proper subset of $E$ is.